# Can't Run My Program

Tags: java

Trying to make my first program "A Basic Mind Game".

Every time I try to run it nothing shows up and don't know what's wrong.

Hope that you can give me some hand or advice.

BTW, I'm pretty much a NOOB at Java Programing so take it easy with the comments :)

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner.*;
import java.util.ArrayList.*;


 public class Main {
 public static void start() {

 int answer = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 + 1) ; 
 int tries = 0 ;
 int player ;
 String name = "name" ;
 String quit = "quit";
 String y = "yes";
 String n = "no";
 String guess = ("player") ;
 String another = ("Y") ;
 Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);


    System.out.println( " Welcome to Guessing Game " ) ;
    System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and 1000 : ");
                    player = input.nextInt();
      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      int currentGuess = -1;



    while(another.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {


      do
      {


               if (guess.equalsIgnoreCase(quit))
  {
   System.out.println("Leaving Us So Soon?");
   System.exit(0);
  }

               try    {
   currentGuess = Integer.parseInt(guess);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) 
                        {
   System.out.println("Stupid Guess I Wont Count That.");
                        player = input.nextInt();
                        tries++;

   }


       if (currentGuess < answer )
          {
   System.out.println("too low");
   player = input.nextInt();
                        tries++;
  }


    else if(currentGuess  > answer )
  {
   System.out.println("too high");
   player = input.nextInt();
                        tries++;
  }
  //if the guess is invalid
  if (currentGuess < 0 || currentGuess > 1000)
  {
   System.out.println("Stupid Guess I Wont Count That.");
                        player = input.nextInt();
                        tries++;
  }
    else if (currentGuess == answer)
  {
   //stop stop watch
   long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   //calculate game time
   long gameTime = endTime - startTime;
   System.out.println("You Rock Dude, Good Job!");

                        System.out.println("You guessed " + tries + " times in " + (int)(gameTime/1000) + " seconds.");
                        System.out.println("Please enter your name.");
            name = input.nextLine();
  }

        } while (player != answer);

      Scanner playGame = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Want to go again?(y/n).....");
    another = playGame.nextLine();


    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I think just one question mark would convey the message better. I also think describing the question in the title would convey the message even better.

Comment: This should teach you to *incrementally* implement and test your program.  You shouldn't have produced this much code without having run it once (even if all it does at the start is print "Welcome to Guessing Game").  Leaving testing to once you've implemented much of the code makes it very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 15):

Your main method is empty.

The main method contains the code that will run when the application starts. If the main method is empty, nothing will happen when you run your application.

Answer (score 3):

If this isn't a troll I'll be stunned.  The reason nothing shows up is because in your
`static void main`  method you don't have any code for the program to execute.

Answer (score 2):

Java's main method is `main`. Thus, you must run your code *from* `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework, however this should do the trick.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main.start();
    }
```

Comment: He shouldn't need to add Main as he is currently in that class.

Comment: -1. Even with the classname, it should be "Main.start();" instead of "Main.Start();"

Comment: Climber104, thx for the help it relly helped, Looks like I got much to learn

Comment: really? -1 for a typo? Benjamin, Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    start();
}
```

Make that change and see if it's better.

Answer (score -1):

After your "public class Main{ " line, put "start();" then proceed your code.