# No error in code, however will not print to console when prompted

Tags: java, printing

Create a class and write the following methods:

1. `int firstDigit(int n)`, returning the first digit of the argument
2. `int lasstDigit(int n)`, returning the last digit of the argument
3. `int digits(int n)`, returning the number of digits of the argument

For example, `firstDigit(1729)` is 1, `lastDigit(1729)` is 9, and `digits(1729)` is 4.

Provide a program that tests your methods from a different class in a non static manner.

Here is my homework question.

```
package homework;

public class HW5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    /*1A)*/static int firstDigit(int n){
        String fd= Integer.toString(n);
        System.out.println(fd.charAt(0));
        return 0;
    }
    /*1B)*/static int lastDigit(int n){
        String ld= Integer.toString(n);
        System.out.println(ld.charAt(ld.length()-1));
        return 0;
    }
    /*1C)*/static int Digits(int n){
        int digits=0;
        String digi= Integer.toString(n);
        for(int x=0; x<digi.length(); x++){
            digits++;
        }
        return digits;
    }

}
```

This is the code I tried. It gives back no Errors it just wont print anything to the console.

Comment: Why do you think it should print anything to the console?

Comment: (Hint: your `main` method is empty.)

Comment: None of those methods is ever called

Comment: Ah, take a look at this one also http://stackoverflow.com/q/3876454/1743880